# Oledb Exception - No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read a csv file using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 in asp.net c# but i am getting an error as "No value given for one or more required parameters."

`my select query :`

```
string query = string.Concat("SELECT a_id, EpisodeId, Logged, [appintmentfollowporreferral] as Appointment, AppointmentType, AppointmentDateAndTime, AppointmentWith, Outcome, RTWStatus, Completed FROM " + appointmentReportsFileName);
```

`here is the code that i am using to read the csv file :`

```
string connString = string.Concat("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;", "Data Source=", filePath, ";", "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=D=Delimited(,)\"");
            //create an OleDbDataAdapter to execute the query
            OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
            //fill the DataTable
            dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
            dAdapter.Dispose();
```

### the file contains all the column names specified in the query string, i have checked the column names for any difference but i couldn't find any difference.

here is csv file that i am trying to read :

---

please some one help me in solving this problem....

Answer (score 0):

Place your column name

e.g.

```
string query = string.Concat("SELECT [a_id], EpisodeId, [Logged], 
[appintmentfollowporreferral] as [Appointment], AppointmentType, AppointmentDateAndTime,
AppointmentWith, [Outcome], RTWStatus, Completed FROM " + appointmentReportsFileName);
```

Also check if all given columns exist or the table name variable (`appointmentReportsFileName`) has valid value

Comment: i tried by placing column names between [] but still i get same error.
i also checked that all the column names exist & even the variable "appointmentReportsFileName" (which is my csv file name) has all the values.
when i use :  "SELECT [a_id], [EpisodeId] as EpisodeId, ...."
it gives an exception of "Circular reference caused by alias 'EpisodeId' in query definition's SELECT list."

Answer (score 0):

Set Breakpoint check what you have in query string to apply in your db